# Java class instantiates straight away without calling constructor?

Tags: java

Just started learning Java.

For some reason i can't create a class without it instantiating an instance of itself?

Can't i just create a class and extend my current class? if i try to call it's internal functions it duplicates the function..

I'm trying to learn about inheritance and how i can make my code more modular

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Character extends ClassAttribute {

    public String classType;
    public int health;
    public Object selection;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Character chris = new Character();
        System.out.println("your class is: " + chris.classType);
        System.out.println("your health is: " + chris.health);
    };

    public Character() {

        ClassAttribute choice = new ClassAttribute();
        this.classType = choice.classType;
        this.health = choice.health;

    }
}

public class ClassAttribute {

    public String classType;
    public int health;
    public String choice;

    public void human() {
        this.health = 100;
        this.classType = "Human";

    }

    public void ai() {
        this.health = 110;
        this.classType = "Ai";
    }

    public ClassAttribute() {
        System.out.println("Choose a class type (Human || Ai)");
        Scanner readClassChoice = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (!"Ai".equals(this.choice) && !"Human".equals(this.choice)) {
            try {
                this.choice = readClassChoice.nextLine();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid class (Ai || Human)");
                readClassChoice.next();
            }
            ;
        }

        if ("Ai".equals(this.choice)) {
            ai();
        } else {
            human();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: *For some reason i can't create a class without it instantiating an instance of itself?* What? *Can't i just create a class and extend my current class?* Huh? *if i try to call it's internal functions it duplicates the function..* Come again?

Comment: An instance of  "class attribute" is being created when this code is run and all its methods along with it. The objective is to inherit another classes methods to add functionality to an existing class.

Comment: Why are you creating an instance then?

Comment: Every time ClassAttribute is called it should return a new instance otherwise every character would be the same right?

Comment: Every time you call any constructor it returns a new instance. I still have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: `Every time ClassAttribute is called it should return a new instance otherwise every character would be the same right?` No, I don't think so.  ALSO: I think you might be getting messed up with `java.lang.Character`  Please change the name of your class to something else.

Comment: Apart from anything else you have an object model problem here. `Character` should have a `ClassAttribute` memtber, not members that are the same as `ClassType`'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Execution Explanation:**
I guess you are confused about the execution order in Character and ClassAttribute classes. One thing you have to remember when extending a class is that the constructor of a class will call the zero-argument constructor of its super class or parent class, and so on until reaching first ancestor.

So in your code, you create an instance of Character in your main method, that would trigger Character constructor, but before creating an instance of ClassAtribute, Character constructor will call ClassAttribute constructor, therefore executing your scanner code.

Once that is done, it will get back to Character constructor and create an instance of ClassAttribute, which again will execute the constructor but for this local variable instance, therefore your Scanner code will be executed again.

So, you have two ClassAtribute classes, one created at main, one created at Character constructor, both executes ClassAtribute constructor.

Because of inheritance you do not have to create an instance of the parent at constructor to access parent methods, you just need to use `this` or `super` keyword to access parent methods

**Bad Sample for Inheritance**
Also, this is not a good sample for inheritance, as you learn java you will find two fundamental relationships: Composition (has a) and Inheritance(is a). If you extend Character from ClassAtribute, your are saying "Character is a ClassAtribute" which seems confusing and wrong. It is more natural saying "Character has an health attribute".

**A better sample**
A more suitable sample would be "a character has an attribute health". An then "An ArtificialIntelligence is a Character" and "A Human is a Character" that can be translated to:

```
class Character {
  String health;
}

class ArtificialIntelligence extends Character { }

class Human  extends Character { }
```

Comment: Your description of what is going on is correct, but I would question the structure that has Character extending CharacterAttribute.  Intuitively, I would say that a character *has* an attribute, not that a character *is* an attribute.

Comment: Right, this sample works for Composition scenario, not Inheritance scenario

Comment: Thanks for the explanation i'm completely new to Java =) It all works now.

Comment: No problem, try fit your code using as baseline the classes I include in the answer and compare both solutions, i think it will be more useful from the learning point of view.